# After deleting ubuntu 18.04 can I install ubuntu 16.04 on top of the same grub bootloader?

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, grub, bootloader

I deleted my previous ubuntu 18.04 partition (alongside my primary Windows 10 system) without deleting the grub bootloader. Now it shows a black screen every time I log on to my system. I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my system. Can I do it without deleting previous Grub Bootloader?

Comment: You can do anything you want. Just try that. Share if you see any error or issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah.

1. just backup old grub files from boot partition (/dev/sda1 if you use eufi) which is mounted at /boot.
2. Install newer ubuntu
3. Replace newer grub files with older ones but let the file grub.conf remain (don't replace it).